# retrieving realtime data from firebase into a textview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i have a simple plain textview which i want to change from firebase.

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.tv_helloworld );

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("hello world");

mDatabase.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener ( ) {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String firsttext = snapshot.getValue ( String.class );
        textView.setText ( firsttext );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
} );
```

i will have multiple textview in same activity if anyone can suggest or sprovide any help i will be greatrfull.

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? So: when you step through this line by line in a debugger, which is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: hello i have just plain textview which i want to change that from firebase and for that i use this code i think the code is wrong i want suggestion regarding this @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions though. Stack Overflow is a horribly inefficient interactive debugger, so you will have to debug the code you shared, and tell us exactly which line doesn't work. --- For example, if you set a breakpoint inside `onDataChange` and run in the debugger, does it reach that breakpoint?

Comment: Sample code: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android?hl=en#0

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.